# How to UPDATE multiple columns using a correlated subquery in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I want to update multiple columns in a table using a correlated subquery. Updating a single column is straightforward:

```
UPDATE route
SET temperature = (SELECT amb_temp.temperature
                   FROM amb_temp.temperature
                   WHERE amb_temp.location = route.location)
```

However, I'd like to update several columns of the route table. As the subquery is much more complex in reality (JOIN with a nested subquery using [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) functions), I want to avoid repeating it like this:

```
UPDATE route
SET
  temperature = (SELECT amb_temp.temperature
                 FROM amb_temp.temperature
                 WHERE amb_temp.location = route.location),
  error = (SELECT amb_temp.error
           FROM amb_temp.temperature
           WHERE amb_temp.location = route.location),
```

Ideally, SQLite would let me do something like this:

```
UPDATE route
SET (temperature, error) = (SELECT amb_temp.temperature, amb_temp.error
                            FROM amb_temp.temperature
                            WHERE amb_temp.location = route.location)
```

Alas, that is not possible. Can this be solved in another way?

Here's what I've been considering so far:

- use INSERT OR REPLACE as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073355/438249). It seems it's not possible to refer to the route table in the subquery.
- prepend the UPDATE query with a [WITH clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), but I don't think that is useful in this case.

For completeness sake, here's the actual SQL query I'm working on:

```
UPDATE route SET (temperature, time_distance) = ( -- (C)
  SELECT  -- (B)
    temperature.Temp,
    MIN(ABS(julianday(temperature.Date_HrMn)
            - julianday(route.date_time))) AS datetime_dist
  FROM temperature
    JOIN (
      SELECT  -- (A)
        *, Distance(stations.geometry,route.geometry) AS distance
      FROM stations
      WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM temperature
        WHERE stations.USAF = temperature.USAF
              AND stations.WBAN_ID = temperature.NCDC
        LIMIT 1
      )
      GROUP BY stations.geometry
      ORDER BY distance
      LIMIT 1
  ) tmp
  ON tmp.USAF = temperature.USAF
     AND tmp.WBAN_ID = temperature.NCDC
)
```

High-level description of this query:

- using `geometry` (= longitude & latitude) and `date_time` from the `route` table,
- (A) find the weather station (`stations` table, uniquely identified by the USAF and NCDC/WBAN_ID columns)

  - closest to the given longitude/latitude (`geometry`)
  - for which temperatures are present in the `temperature` table
- (B) find the `temperature` table row

  - for the weather station found above
  - closest in time to the given timestamp
- (C) store the temperature and "time_distance" in the `route` table

Comment: You could put the subquery without the correlation into the WITH, and then use simple correlated subqueries to select from that.

Comment: Is that possible with the actual SQL query I added to the question? Will that not be much slower?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE route
SET
  temperature = q.temperature,
  error = q.error
FROM ( SELECT * FROM amb_temp ) q
WHERE q.location = route.location
```

?