# Updated related model using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models

```
class Alert(Base):
    __table_name__  = 'alerts'
    #fields left out for ease
    channel_id = Column(Integer)

class AlertStatus(Base):
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='pk_alert_state_change'),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['reason_id'],
            ['reasons.id'],
            name='fk_alert_status_change_reason_id__reasons'
        ),

        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['alert_id'],
            ['alerts.id'],
            name='fk_alert_status_change_alert_id__alert'
        ),

        UniqueConstraint(
            'alert_id', 'reason_id',
            name='ux_alert_status_change__alert_id__reason_id'
        )
    )
    #fields left out for ease

    status = Column(String)
    alert_id = Column(Integer)
    reason_id = Column(Integer)
    date = Column(UTCDateTime, default=utcnow_tzaware, onupdate=utcnow_tzaware) #UTCDateTime is just a custom column to return tz aware datetime objects. 

    alert = relationship('Alert' backref=backref('status', uselist=False)
    reason = relationship('Reason', backref='status')
```

I want to filter Alerts with specific channel_id and update their status like so (but it's not working)

```
session.query(Alert).filter(channel_id==3).update({AlertStatus.status:'newstatus', AlertStatus.reason_id:5})
```

but I get the following error

```
CompileError: Unconsumed column names: status, reason_id
```

How do I update the related objects from within the object.

I also tried this:

```
 db.get_session().query(models.AlertStatus).filter(
        Alert.channel_id == 3). \
        update({'status': 'newstatus',
                'reason_id': 5}, synchronize_session=False)
```

but I get

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "FROM": syntax error [SQL: u'UPDATE alerts_status SET reason_id=?, status=?, date=? FROM alerts WHERE alerts.channel_id = ?'] [parameters: (5, u'open', '2017-03-14 11:24:19.565573', 1)]
```

It is tested in sqlite inmemory db

Comment: The first query is trying to update `AlertStatus` columns, but selects `Alert` as the table to update, so that's clearly wrong. The latter version has the [multiple table update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#multiple-table-updates) almost right (update `AlertStatus`, join `Alert`), except it is missing the join condition. Finally SQLite does not support multiple table updates, [not easily at least](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071087/update-multiple-columns-on-a-row-with-a-single-select-in-sqlite). Single column correlated subqueries in UPDATE are supported.

Comment: so what would be a correct answer?

Comment: "Don't use SQLite for testing, if your end DB is not SQLite", but that doesn't help – and you haven't actually specified if you're just testing in SQLite, or if it'll be the target as well. The multi column multi table update is tricky. You could perhaps use the `INSERT OR REPLACE` trick described in the linked Q/A, if you either know that the rows always exist beforehand, or it is OK that they're inserted if not.

Comment: After some testing you'd probably get surprising results with REPLACE since it considers all primary key and unique constraint violations. So when you'd want to replace some other row to contain a new `reason_id`, you'd most probably overwrite a row you did not mean to update, because of the (alert_id, reason_id) unique constraint. Or perhaps this is exactly what you want :)